# iOS13 OnDevice Speech Recognition (supportsOnDeviceRecognition flag)

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, offline

I'm trying to get the iOS 13 OnDevice Speech recognition working. However validating the supportsOnDeviceRecognition flag, which is the preliminary step to enable OnDevice recognition, always returns false. I'm using iPad 6th Gen with iOS 13.3. I tested supportsOnDeviceRecognition flag with other devices and see it works only for some.

```
private var speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en_US"))
.
.
.
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    if speechRecognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition ?? false {
        recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
    }
}
```

I tried reading supportsOnDeviceRecognition multiple times after few seconds delay between each read per the below note, but it doesn't help.

> According to the iOS 13 release notes:
>
> The supportsOnDeviceRecognition property always returns false the first time it’s accessed. After a few seconds, accessing it again returns the correct value.

Has anyone encountered similar problem and how to go about this?

Comment: The release notes are describing a bug. The bug has been fixed. So do not cite the release notes in this way.

Comment: This is still an issue on iOS14.

Answer (score 0):

I got the flag supportsOnDeviceRecognition finally returning true. I have to go to Settings > Siri & Search > Siri Voice.. I noticed the American (the one I want) was selected and it started downloading the dialect. After the download is complete, restarted the device and the flag became true.

Answer (score 0):

Op is not impacted by this, but readers coming in from Google, be aware `supportsOnDeviceRecognition` is locale dependent. If you init your `SFSpeechRecognizer` with the locale you are targeting, it will just start returning `true` assuming the locale Siri dictionary is downloaded on the device:

```swift
var unLocalizedSpeechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer.init()
// unLocalizedSpeechRecognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition is most likely `false`

// change en-US to whatever locale you are targeting
var localizedSpeechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer.init(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
// localizedSpeechRecognizer.supportsOnDeviceRecognition is most likely `true`
// if that local has been downloaded
```