# SFSpeechRecognizer not allowing non-system on device locales

Tags: swift, xcode, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm trying to recognise English speech spoken in multiple locales on the users device (macOS). The official WWDC video shows that this is supported.
[image]
However if I try to create an on-device speech recogniser in any language other than my system setting it fails.

```
import UIKit
import Speech


let speechRecogniser = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-IN"))
speechRecogniser?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition = true
print(speechRecogniser?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition)
```

returns false

```
let speechRecogniser = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-AU"))
    speechRecogniser?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition = true
    print(speechRecogniser?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition)
```

returns true

Supported locales

```
for locale in SFSpeechRecognizer.supportedLocales() {
                print(locale)
            }
```

Returns the following:

> es-CL (fixed) es-419 (fixed) sv-SE (fixed) de-DE (fixed) en-GB (fixed)
>   es-CO (fixed) hi-IN (fixed) fr-CH (fixed) ar-SA (fixed) vi-VN (fixed)
>   de-CH (fixed) en-US (fixed) en-PH (fixed) zh-HK (fixed) ru-RU (fixed)
>   id-ID (fixed) fi-FI (fixed) tr-TR (fixed) it-IT (fixed) ja-JP (fixed)
>   uk-UA (fixed) wuu-CN (fixed) nl-NL (fixed) da-DK (fixed) cs-CZ (fixed)
>   fr-CA (fixed) ms-MY (fixed) he-IL (fixed) zh-CN (fixed) es-US (fixed)
>   hu-HU (fixed) sk-SK (fixed) fr-FR (fixed) nl-BE (fixed) es-MX (fixed)
>   en-AU (fixed) zh-TW (fixed) it-CH (fixed) el-GR (fixed) ko-KR (fixed)
>   ro-RO (fixed) yue-CN (fixed) pt-BR (fixed) es-ES (fixed) hi-Latn
>   (fixed) en-ZA (fixed) en-NZ (fixed) ca-ES (fixed) en-IE (fixed) fr-BE
>   (fixed) pt-PT (fixed) en-ID (fixed) en-SA (fixed) hi-IN-translit
>   (fixed) en-IN (fixed) nb-NO (fixed) hr-HR (fixed) en-CA (fixed) en-SG
>   (fixed) de-AT (fixed) pl-PL (fixed) th-TH (fixed) en-AE (fixed)

To confirm my issue wasn't related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59991553/341994) post, I change my Siri voice as below (which downloaded additional files).
[image]

Comment: I think there is no locale has abbreviation like `en-IN` could you please print `print(Locale(identifier: "en-IN"))`? I think it will be `nil` if it is not please print `print(SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-IN")))` or `print(speechRecogniser)`

Comment: Check this gist to find abbreviations -> https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Comment: Please see my edited post showing supported locales as en-IN. I'll try en_IN shortly.

Comment: @emrcftci - en-IN (fixed)
Optional(<SFSpeechRecognizer: 0x600002624fc0>)

Comment: BTW this is macOS, not iOS.

Comment: So it seems Apple didn't promise that every machine would do on-device recognition for every listed locale. They promised that on-device recognition for every listed locale exists. The rule you've deduced, that it works for the device's _actual_ locale only, would not be unreasonable, and it wouldn't contradict what they said (would it?).

Comment: @matt - And this is where I've landed, that it supports those locales, but will only work for your current locale. The next obvious question for me would be (and is why I posted this), what do I need to install or configure to support additional locales?

Comment: It seems from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59991553/341994 that something has to be explicitly downloaded. That makes sense; there is a "package" of intelligence that needs to be present on the machine before recognition can happen.

Comment: Thanks @matt - I did see that post. Please note I've updated my post to make it clearer this is for macOS, not iOS

Comment: Yes, but I'm not so sure that changes anything...? Siri is the dictation engine. Did you actually download (and switch to) the Siri English(India) engine? Look in the Siri system preferences...

Comment: Yes I did try that. I've just updated my post with a screenshot

Comment: Interestingly I'm seeing the following output in the console: [AFPreferences languageCode] No language code saved, but Assistant is enabled - returning: en-AU

Comment: For future readers: "Downloading a language" is done in [Language & Region > Translation Languages](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchldd8b3c15/mac#:~:text=Download%20languages%20to%20translate%20on%20your%20device). A subset of [12 languages](https://www.apple.com/uk/macos/feature-availability/#translate-system-wide-translation) that are supported languages for offline use

Comment: @JakobLindskog The translation has noting to do with speech recognition. The supported languages are different and speech recognition was available in earlier versions of iOS before translation had been added.